# Ocamldebug: Lost connection to process

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, ocaml

I recently switched to Ocaml 4.03.0 (installed using Opam) and started seeing erratic behaviors from ocamldebug on examples that previously went through without any problem.

In specific, I load up the byte code into ocamldebug, set arguments and run it. I don't set any breakpoints, I just want the debugger to hit an assert failure that both byte code (outside the debugger) and native code hit. Instead of reaching the assert, ocamldebug stops after running for a while saying

```
Lost connection to process  1234 (active process) 
between time x and y.   
Segmentation fault (core dumped). 
Restart from time z to get closer of the problem? (y or n)".
```

If I try to get closer the problem by saying "n" then running again, this problem keeps repeating.

Apart from minor changes to my code (like additional print statements) nothing has changed in my set up except the Ocaml version. A collaborator of mine also has this problem, both with Ocaml 3.12.0 (installed from sources) and 4.03.0 (installed from Opam).

Why is this happening? And is there fix to this? Any insight into this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One possible explanation of the behavior is that your code is actually segfaulting. If you have pure OCaml with no unsafe constructs, any segfault is an implementation error (in OCaml itself). The OCaml implementation is pretty well wrung out by now, though. So, do you have unsafe constructs or external code in other languages? On a separate note, you could try saying 'y' instead of 'n', maybe you can find where it's happening. Finally, if you can show a full example that would help tremendously.

Comment: As I said neither the byte code nor the native code seg faults. They get to the assert I put in. Only debugger has this issue. I have used imperative code in several places but no unsafe constructs that I can think of.   As for an example, this is large code base and it is hard to isolate a snippet.

Comment: Without a way to reproduce the problem, you're essentially asking if this is a known issue. I looked through the bug reports at [Mantis](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis) and didn't see anything, but others will know much more than I.